# Crontab Command Question

Tags: cron, reboot

I'm trying to run xmrig at reboot using the following command in crontab:

```
@reboot cd /xmrig/build && ./xmrig && "password"
```

When I check the cron logs I recieve:

```
cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-04-03 19:54:55 UTC; 1min 24s ago
       Docs: man:cron(8)
   Main PID: 2418 (cron)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 3832)
     Memory: 2.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
             └─2418 /usr/sbin/cron -f

Apr 03 19:54:55 odroid cron[2418]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Apr 03 19:54:55 odroid cron[2418]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Apr 03 19:54:55 odroid CRON[2420]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 03 19:54:55 odroid CRON[2426]: (root) CMD (/path/to/xmrig -B)
Apr 03 19:54:55 odroid CRON[2420]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Apr 03 19:54:55 odroid CRON[2420]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 03 19:54:55 odroid CRON[2421]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user odroid by (uid=0)
Apr 03 19:54:55 odroid CRON[2447]: (odroid) CMD (cd /xmrig/build && ./xmrig && "password")
Apr 03 19:54:55 odroid CRON[2421]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Apr 03 19:54:55 odroid CRON[2421]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user odroid
```

"password" being my actual password.  Any thoughts on how I can get this to work.  I have tried cd /root/xmrig/build and omitted the password and that didn't work either.

Comment: `&&` is used to chain *commands* - you can't use it to provide a password interactively (if that's what you are trying to do - I am not familiar with `xmrig`)

Comment: How did you edit the crontab? Did you use `sudo crontab -e` or plain `crontab -e`?

Comment: passwords need to be kept SAFE. That means never ever do you include them in scripts that can log it. please use the "--config="  options xmrig provides.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be helpful: [Command line options - XMRig](https://xmrig.com/docs/miner/command-line-options)

You could try:

```
@reboot cd /xmrig/build && ./xmrig --pass= PASSWORD
```

***Addendum***: [@Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind) is absolutely right about not storing clear text passwords inside scripts you can generate a JSON file for for usage in your cron script [here](https://config.xmrig.com/) and have it load something like this:

```
@reboot cd /xmrig/build && ./xmrig --config=/PATH/TO/FILE.json
```

Comment: Passwords in plain text in crontab is bad.  xmrig provides a "--config="  option to use a file in json format to provide user and password.